# Wordpress - can't install Ultimate Post Type Manager and Ultimate Taxonomy Manager

Tags: wordpress

WP v3.2 came out the same day that I installed v3.1.3, but, unfortunately, my host doesn't have PHP5, so I'm stuck with this version. So I tried to install Ultimate Post Type Manager and Ultimate Taxonomy Manager using the Add New Plugin page, and it downloaded them fine. However, when trying to activate them, I got the following fatal errors:

**UTM:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /www/inbulgaria.org/rock/root/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-taxonomy-manager/ct.class.php on line 64
```

**UPTM:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /www/inbulgaria.org/rock/root/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-post-type-manager/class-fieldType.php on line 3
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was PHP5 after all, as I learned soon afterwards.